# NPE at android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android

I am using Facebook android SDK which embed webview in dialog. when ever i re installs application on droid with android 2.2 , webview crashes for first time giving following stack trace. I google it but no luck so far . Please let me know if anyone of you already have workaround for this problem.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged(WebView.java:4177)
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
    06-29 10:40:59.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10368):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662
```

Comment: http://www.zubha-labs.com/workaround-for-null-pointer-excpetion-in-webv  I have added patch for this problem , check out

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is you don't have registered your application on Facebook, i have face also this problem , now i have create a new app and change key and that is working fine for me..

in my case, i was using the key of my previous application then shows this error, now i have created app on facebook with new packagename and class name, then in is working fine for me.. thanks