# Android Facebook-sdk crash

Tags: android, facebook, webview

app crashes when I want to share

this is code

```
private void share() {
    facebookClient = new Facebook(APP_API_ID);
    facebookClient.authorize(this,
            new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);
}

@Override
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

    if (!values.containsKey("post_id"))
    {

    try {
            String response = facebookClient.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("name","Name");
            parameters.putString("description", "Description" );
            parameters.putString("link", "Link");
            parameters.putString("picture","Picture");
            response = facebookClient.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
               Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }

     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
```

this is crash log

```
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged(WebView.java:4198)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-17 18:22:49.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there a solution

Thanks

Comment: Post the complete stack trace. Also - NullPointerExceptions are the easiest to find. All you have to do is debug, and step up to the point where the NPE occurs, and evaluate your variables.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525005/npe-at-android-webkit-webview-onwindowfocuschanged

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
String response = facebookClient.request("me");
```

with

```
String response = "";
```

Comment: Do you know which line returns the nullpointerException? you can debug and break at each line until the app crashes.

Comment: Please provide the full logcat trace as it is not clear which line causes this exception from the portion you provided. It is strange that it works on Galaxy and not G1. Does it work on all emulator SDKs?